# Placeholder text for Tag Input is cut off

Tags: bug, tags

I went to task a question on Arqade and notices that where you type the tags, the place holder telling you to type tags there has been cut off

[image: Arcade]
[image: Stack Overflow]
[image: Stack Overflow Meta]
[image: Meta Stack Exchnage]

**OS:** Windows 10 64-bit

**Browser:** Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

<sub>14/09/2018 9:03am AEST - also it appears that the resized image generation for uploaded images are not working but recall seeing this reported already</sub>